# Jackson no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('7b70f9fa-3861-4552-a72c-7fca341a4554')

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, serialization, jackson

Asset

```
@Column(name = "id")
private UUID id;

// ...

@JsonSerialize(using = TerminalListSerializer.class)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "asset", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private List<Terminal> terminals;
```

Terminal

```
@Column(name = "id")
private UUID id;

// ...

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="asset_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "Terminal_Asset_FK"))
private Asset asset;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "terminal", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Channel> channels;
```

Channel

```
@Column(name = "id")
private UUID id;

// ...

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="term_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "Channel_Terminal_FK"))
private Terminal terminal;
```

Custom Serializer

```
public class TerminalListSerializer extends StdSerializer<List<Terminal>> {

    public TerminalListSerializer() {
        super((Class<List<Terminal>>) null);
    }

    public TerminalListSerializer(Class<List<Terminal>> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<Terminal> terminals, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {

        List<UUID> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Terminal item : terminals) {
            ids.add(item.getId());
        }
        jsonGenerator.writeObject(ids);
    }
}
```

I have 3 entities, with the relations as you can see above. In order to avoid circular reference between `Asset` and `Terminal`, I decided to use a custom serializer. This serializer in place, Asset will contain only Terminal IDs and solve my problem. But I'm having another problem now, because Terminal has a relationship with another entity (`Channel`) which gives me this error when I try to update a Terminal.

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `my.package.Terminal` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('7b70f9fa-3861-4552-a72c-7fca341a4554')
 at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 1, column: 3320] (through reference chain: my.package.Terminal["channels"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->my.package.Channel["terminal"]->my.package.Terminal["asset"]->my.package.Asset["terminals"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are serializing list of `Terminal` objects into list of UUID strings. So you get error during deserialization, since Jackson can't create `Terminal` instance from `String` value. Use custom deserializer for terminals or add `Terminal(String uuid)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's having a problem deserializing the UUID type. You can either register a custom deserializer for it or simply use strings in this particular case